# Multi-threaded access to a Queue in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, mutex

So basically I have two threads: One generates combinations of a String and appends them to a Queue that is a class member.
The second thread is supposed to print everything that is in that queue to a file. If the queue is empty I should wait until there is another element and so forth.

```
 std::mutex m;
Class c{
  std::queue<std::string> q;
  std::ofstream file;

  void print(std::string str){
    file << str << "\n";
  } // Print to file

  void generate(){
    str = "abc" // do stuff
    q.push(str);
  }

}
```

When I'm using `std::mutex` the program's performance gets really bad.
I think I need a function that manages access to the queue so that i can write and print simultaneously. **How do I do that?**

```
void Generator::print() {
    int c = 0;
    while (c < totalN){
        if(!printQueue.empty()){
            fileStream << printQueue.front() << '\n';
            printQueue.pop();
            c++;
        }
    }
}

void Generator::getCombinations(unsigned long start, unsigned long end) {
// Fill with dummy elements
std::string comb(length, ' ');
std::string temp(length, ' ');
auto total_n = static_cast<unsigned long>(std::pow(elementCount, length));
for (auto i = start; i < end; ++i) {
    auto n = i;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < length; ++j) {
        comb[comb.size() - j - 1] = charPool[n % elementCount];
        n /= elementCount;
    }
    temp = comb;
    for (auto f : tasks) (this->*f)(temp); // Call addQueue func
}
}


void Generator::addToQueue(std::string &str) {
    m.lock();
    printQueue.push(str);
    m.unlock();
}
```

For some reason I get bad-access errors because the prints functions tries to print something from an empty queue which seems kind of impossible to me because this part of code is only executed if the queue is not empty...

Comment: Please show your actual mutex-using code and your two threads. How much work does each thread do while holding the mutex?

Comment: What are you doing when your mutex is locked? When and where do you lock it? How are you using this class and the queue it contains? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, otherwise it will be very hard to help you. Also please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: added more code

Comment: It looks like you are protecting only access to queue inside of `addToQueue` which does not provide any sync so you are getting UB due to a race condition.

Comment: But I have a global mutex variable

Comment: Which you don't lock in the `print` function. Which will lead to data-races.

Comment: Just having a mutex alone doesn't do anything. You also have to actually use that mutex to actually protect entrance to *every* [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section). Which you don't. In your example, all code that accessess your `printQueue` *in any way* is a critical section. Also, you wanna have a look at `std::scoped_lock` and `std::unique_lock` to automate the acquire and release of locks for you…

Comment: Mutex synchronization works by blocking thread execution at `m.lock();` invocation until mutex gets unlocked. So if you don't invoke it infront of all the places  where `printQueue` is accessed there will be a race condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Generator::Print` function, you would do best to swap out the shared queue for an empty one and then consume the contents:

```cpp
void Generator::print() {
  int todo = totalN;
  while (todo) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
    std::queue<std::string> temp;
    { // Lock only taken for this section
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
      std::swap(temp, q);
    }
    todo -= temp.size();
    while (!temp.empty()) {
      fileStream << temp.front() << '\n';
      temp.pop();
    }
  }
}
```

This takes the lock at most every 500ms, and only long enough to replace `q` with `temp`. It can print the contents at its own pace then.

Note that if generation would be much slower than printing, you can get away with just popping off one at a time instead of swapping the queue like I did here.

Comment: The for loop does not work for me. I think you can't iterate over a queue this way..

Comment: You are correct. I edited my answer to use `front` and `pop` instead of a for-each loop.

Comment: Thanks! That did the job for me! +1

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard problem known as a [producer/consumer queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).
The current out-of-the-box solution for this in C++ is the [condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). If you follow the link, you will find an example solution. Notice some features you are missing

- Always lock/unlock via std::lock_guard or std::unique_lock.
- Use a condition variable to control when each thread wakes-up or sleeps, if speed is important.
- Every access to the structure must be synchronized. This includes pushing/popping and even const functions like the call to empty.

Given where your code is, and given that the problem is well known. I would suggest that you should start looking for existing code. From a scan read [this](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/04/c11-concurrency-tutorial-advanced-locking-and-condition-variables.html) looks like a reasonable overview. In particular, look at the "bounded buffer" section.
Boost has some implementations which do not use mutex. This is more advanced than you seem to need. I would not advise this for you but others may well find this of interest.
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html